# Bob said a dog broke his leg

Tags: meaning

I was talking with my colleague today, He said:
**Bob said a dog broke his leg.**
Does he means dog's leg broke or Bob's leg broke by the dog.
(I came from China & English is not so good)

Comment: Without context, it's ambiguous. In context the speakers would probably know whether or not Bob's leg was broken, which would resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: It's the dog. Bob was not here today, he went to take the dog to a doctor. For grammar, it should means bob's leg was broke, right? If the dog's leg broke the sentence should be : Bob said that a dog has broke his leg.

Comment: English idiom permits *X broke his leg* for *X's leg was broken*--it doesn't imply that *X* caused his own leg to break, only that *X* experienced his leg being broken.  By they way, we say the leg was *broken*, not *broke*--*broke* as an adjective usually means *without money*.

Comment: As @StoneyB says, it's technically ambiguous. But I think the indefinite article "a" before "dog" affects the interpretation by making it less likely that we are talking about a dog with a broken leg.

Comment: @sumelic I don't think the choice of article affects the interpretation. The choice of "a" or "the" just depends on whether you're referring to a specific dog.

Comment: @sumelic Sorry, I edited my comment to remove the replacement sentence, and just talk about articles.

Comment: @Barmar: I agree that the definiteness of the dog is how you determine which article to use, but I think whether we are talking about a definite or indefinite dog has implications for the most likely pronoun reference. (My understanding is that the dog is "specific," as a technical matter, either way: if I say "A dog broke my/his leg," I'm talking about a specific dog even if you don't know which one it is.)

Comment: @StoneyB Just pondering your second comment for a moment, if I knew that the direct cause of someone breaking their leg was the action of another party (be it dog or human), I think I would be less likely to say *X broke his leg*, unless I was reporting the matter some time later, and the circumstances of the break were unimportant. *X just broke his leg* does seem to me to carry the suggestion of an accident, in which there was not a clear guilty party.

Comment: Relevant story [here](https://blueapsara.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/just-go-with-it/).  As it happens, the person I was talking to was Chinese-born, but I think a native speaker could have made the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**, welcome, but [there is a separate Stack Exchange for English learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) where basic grammar questions will get a warmer welcome.

**Second**, some English teachers and tests in China would imagine that "Bob said a dog broke his leg" would *need* to refer to Bob's leg since they imagine that animals should properly be referenced as "it". If anything, the opposite is true. It's more common in American and British English to refer to beloved pets as "he" or "she".

Grammatically,

## it's ambiguous

and your "his" could refer to either Bob or his dog, depending on the rest of the context. You could clarify by rephrasing it as

> Bob said a dog broke its leg.

or

> Bob said his leg was broken by a dog.

You don't really need to. In this case, it's **much more likely** that a male dog accidentally broke his own leg than that he somehow broke a man's leg. Dogs can *bite* or *bruise* legs easily but *breaking* one is probably caused by a fall after tripping over one. (A bite so powerful that it broke a bone would more likely be described in terms of the bite.) You could say "that dog broke my leg" in the sense that it was his *fault* but that's a matter of angry blame more than simple description.

**Third**, you did a good job and everyone here understood your English. That said, even though you remembered to make dog countable, your sentence really means that *some random dog* broke its leg, which has nothing to do with Bob. The exception would be if Bob is already known to own lots of dogs. Otherwise, better to say

> Bob said **his** dog broke its leg.

People aren't always careful, so that might be your colleague's mistake. Even more common would be someone saying *Bob said his dog broke his leg*, which should mean Bob's leg was broke but really (given the context) probably actually means that the speaker just isn't being careful about their pronouns.

Comment: @PengZuo Concerning your proposed correction, no, it's much worse. The present perfect (*~ has done* or *~ have done*) is really hard since Chinese doesn't have anything like it but

Comment: **A** The only difference between *has broken* (not *has broke* except in dialectal English) and *broke* is the tense of the verb. It doesn't change the subject, which remains grammatically uncertain and semantically likely to be the dog.

Comment: **B** The reason the present perfect is so tricky is because it essentially describes the *same action* as the past tense but from a *different point of view*. "He broke his leg" is talking about something that happened in the past. "He has broken his leg" is talking about the same action in terms of its effect on the present: he is a person who has experienced a broken leg; he can't going running today; &c.

Comment: Great deductive reasoning, but you might have missed a clue.  People refer to their beloved pets as "he" or "she", so a pet's leg would be "his" leg rather than "its" leg.  So if "his" leg referred to the dog, Bob would not use the generic "a" to refer to the dog.  He would say "my" dog broke his leg.  Well, unless maybe he was just crazy in love with any and all dogs and was close enough to determine its gender.  In that case, "a" would refer to a random dog he wasn't familiar with.  A dog could break a person's leg by knocking them over or running into the leg, so that one isn't a good clue.

Comment: @fixer1234 With respect, I didn't miss any of that except for (correctly) stating that it unlikely that a dog might break a human leg by contact. (You can still *blame* the dog, of course.) You, on the other hand, seem to have missed that Bob isn't the one speaking.

Comment: Excellent point.  OK, you win.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 Aw, you're supposed to fight back =(